# Where can I find crash feedback from users in the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

When a crash occurs in an application installed via the Google Play app, user's have the option to Send Feedback.

[image: Send Feedback]

A user can optional write feedback to describe the problem they have encountered and then submit their crash report.

1. Is the written feedback provided by the user available anywhere in the Google Play Console?
2. Can the feedback be associated with a stack trace of the crash the user encountered?

Comment: did you find where it is?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After talking with google support iv received this answer -

"The console has been updated since the IO and some of the function you had in the past is now redundant."

Google has removed the "crash feedback" in the latest update.

Comment: Cool so the pissed off customer's crash report just disappears.. Thanks, Google! Certainly not redundant, I sent a few logs myself and they never came through.. maybe its just slow?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that we can download the user feedback via GSUTIL. Has anyone had luck with that?

Comment: According to this page on Google Support; as of May 2018 you cannot download detailed reports for crashes and ANRs using GSUTIL.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export

Comment: I really don't understand why Google hates Android developers. :/

Comment: anyone found where it is??

Comment: User crash reports are certainly not redundant as they sometimes provide valuable information.

Comment: Any update on that? I'm also trying to find the logs I sent to myself after some startup crash that happens only on release builds and not even all of them....

Comment: I'm so pissed off that user feedback just vanishes into thin air. Why is the report dialog still there then, especially as crash reports are sent automatically regardless of the user reporting it or not. Also, "User feedback" is redundant? Thanks Google!

Answer (score 0):

1.>Open your google console as registered user where you uploaded your app.
link.

2.click on Download Report.

3.click on Crashes and ANRs.

4.select your app name from serch box.select the app which report you want to check.

5.you will get your result as two different option ...

a. Crash report which you can download if you want.
b. ANR reports.

Comment: from google console we will get only exception cause of which app got crashed . but if we need user feedback or any user msg regarding crash then we have to get that from app, from  where user will  send their msg to our api . and then we will get those messages.

Comment: we can get user review report too . from google api console. there is a option Reviews.

Comment: Crash reports don't have user messages.

Comment: Automatic crash reports don't have user messages. To view crash reports with user messages click on "Anrs & Crashes" on the left menu and then click on a small link "previous area" below the android vitals banner. Because i am from germany, it's possible that the links in quotes slightly differ. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Vall0n The 'Previous area' is now removed. Any idea where the messages will be now?

Comment: @arul No, I don't know where the messages are now, or if they are still available...  Sry.

Comment: Has anyone found where they live yet? This is ridiculous lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it :

- **For internal testing** : it is in Play console, in "Pre-launch reports" > "Overview"
- **For production** : it is in left menu, in "Statistics"

[image: Play console menu]

Comment: I tried your solution but I cannot see the feedbacks I reported from a Android 6.0 device :(

Answer (score -2):

Go to google console->select you application ->left side menu-> Android vitals->Crashes and ANR's.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=en