# Where does the feedback Messages from crashed Android-Apps appear?

Tags: android, error-handling, crash, google-sites

I've some Apps in Google play store.
If an App crashes at a device, you are able to send feedback (own Message) which has logfiles attached.

Where does this messages recurved? Is it only for Google's Iinternal usage, or can I (as Developer of the App) see this reports anywhere (developer-console, Google play...)?

Comment: It seems like Google has removed the "crash feedback" in the latest update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527229/where-can-i-find-crash-feedback-from-users-in-the-google-play-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Google and got the answer that Google removed this section.
So you have no chance to get those reports at all.

I wonder that they don't also remove the ability to enter something for the user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open google play console
2. Open App you want to see crashes
3. from the left panel click on Android vitals
4. ANRs & crashes
   You will see two tabs ANR and crashes, there your app's crashes

Comment: I know those one, you've described, but I never found the comments, I've added as Feedback in the Form. So that's why I wonder where this Stuff appears